# Missing Web Management Service on IIS (WIN8)

Tags: asp.net, iis, msbuild

I have seen this asked here before, but none of the other posts solved my issue, so here goes nothing.

We are attempting to use Web Deploy on IIS to automatically deploy our application to a test environment. The idea, besides bettering our deployment process, is to allow Jenkins to deploy our application to IIS and run a few automated tests.

For this we are attempting to use MSBuild along with a deployment profile on our web app. The IIS lies on a Win8 virtual machine, where we try to run MSBuild and it fails because the Web Management Service is not up, and it doesn't show anywhere on the IIS management software.

I have the Web Deploy feature installed, as I have seen from Web Platform Installer, but the Web Management Service icon is nowhere to be found. I have found and started the service manually on the Windows Services configuration, but that doesn't seem to have helped either.

A few other observations:

- "IIS: Management Services" item doesn't seem to show up on my Web Platform Installer;
- I tried changing my installation (under Windows' Add an remove programs) to include web management, id didn't help
- I enabled IIS' Web Management on Windows' "Add and remove features" settings. Also nothing shows up on my manager.
- My Windows language is set to Portuguese. I may have missed the config due to bad translation, but that's unlikely.

So, how do I get the service to run so I can configure it on my IIS and finally deploy my application?

Comment: As said by @Pankaj below. Check this: http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy-on-iis-80-or-later Read section:" Remote Publishing Cannot Be Set up on Windows 8.0 or 8.1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client OSs doesn't come with Web Management Service. You cannot set up remote publishing using Web Deploy for a site that is hosted in IIS on Windows 8.0 or 8.1. You need server OS for same.

Comment: So does that mean we will never be able to assemble an IC solution for that project in that environment? Will we need a machine with a server OS just to be able to deploy our application programatically?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. You need server OS to test this functionality. Please refer [this](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy-on-iis-80-or-later#00) link for more details.

Comment: I see. I will have to come up with a solution for making the deploy programatically if that is possible, as the IC solution is in the same machine as the server. I wonder if that will be possible. Thank you, Pankaj!